# Read Files Using Lua by Directory Using Command Prompt

Tags: lua

I was trying to read a .txt file using lua in command prompt, I'm using 'Lua For Windows' but in the way I tried it's not working, it don't give me any error, it don't return anything, not even 'nil'.

I tried this:

```lua
file = io.open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\a.txt", "r") --(and my user's name)
io.input(file)
print(io.read())
io.close(file)
```

Comment: In Lua 5.2+, you get an error message: `invalid escape sequence near '\U'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash is an escape character in Lua quoted strings.

Try `"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\a.txt"`.

Or avoid the issue using long strings: `[[C:\Users\user\Desktop\a.txt]]`.

Comment: What the 'return slash' does exactly? You put it and the upper file name?